# MySQL/Laravel/Vue -Can a single form input submit multiple values to multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

I haven't been able to find an answer to this and I'm new to backend development but essentially I wanted to know if: I have a form  could I give it 2 name="" fields somehow and give the  2 value="" fields so that when the user chooses an option it would store two separate values in 2 separate sql columns? Or what would be the best way to have 1 sql column relate to the value of another column? Sorry if that is confusing.

To better understand what I am trying to do is when a user selects a time option,
it would also create an energy required field ie. 15 mins would = 1 energy...
I would like to be able to display the time and the energy so I need both columns.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand you have an input in a vue component and want to use the input in two separate ways. How about:

```
<template>
  <input
  v-model="time"
  @change="makeEnergy"
  >
</template>
<script>
  data(){
    return {
      time:0,
      energy:0
    },
  methods: {
    makeEnergy() {
      this.energy = this.time/15
    }

</script>
```

Then you can post the two data elements as you like.